# Excel formula for time comparision

Tags: excel, datetime

while writing an formula for data in a excel cell

if an excel cell contains an integer we can use the statement
if (cell.value > 100 )

but when the excel cell contains a time duration in the format min:sec and we have to compare value greater than 3 minutes duration how to write the statement.

if (cell.value > 03:00 )

is this statement allowed in a formula, or is there a better way to express this ?

Comment: Do you mean a `formula` [for data in excel cell] rather than `algorithm` ?

Comment: yes it would solve my problem if i get the forumula i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if(cell.value > Time(0,3,0))
```

Comment: @silverkid: if that solved your problem, please marked as answered. Same with your other posts today that you say have been answered in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your minute cells are correct Excel timestamp (ie. hh:mm:ss formated mm:ss), you can use `=MINUTE(XX) > 3`